# How to print log during karma Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am a beginner for Angular, recently I started working on Angular.
I have written some unit testing code, as follows.

```
it('fetch data should be correct',
inject(
  [HttpTestingController, Service2Service],
  (
    httpMock: HttpTestingController,
    dataService: Service2Service
  ) =>{
        dataService.getData().subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          console.info("HttpEventType.Response",HttpEventType.Response);
          switch (event.type) {
            case HttpEventType.Response:{
              console.log("body",event.body);
              expect(event.body.length).toEqual(110);
            }
          }
        });
      }
  )
```

);

I am trying to print using console.log but it not printing on console.
Kindly suggest another way to print log.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try by putting `captureConsole` to property client in `karma.conf.js`:

```
client: {
      captureConsole: true,
      mocha: {
        bail: true
      }
    }
```

For more info refer -

- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha/issues/47

Comment: have you checked this thread https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha/issues/47?

Comment: You can see on the last statement, where they clearly said that "still it is not working".